# IE8 + Jquery ajax call giving parsererror from dJango : for json data which seems valid in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

The ajax call works fine in FF.
the data returned is in JSON here is an example from FF firebug -

> {"noProfiles": "No profiles have been created, lets start now !"}

When I try to print the error in IE8 (& in compatibility modes as well), it says "parsererror".
But the output seems to be valid JSON.
Here is the ajax function call I'm making.
Any pointers would be great !

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "GET",   
    url: "/get_all_profile_details/",   
    data: "",   
    dataType: "json",  
    beforeSend: function() {alert("before send called");},  
    success: function(jsonData) {  
        alert("data received");  
    },  
    error: function(xhr, txt, err){  
        alert("xhr: " + xhr + "\n textStatus: " + txt + "\n errorThrown: " + err);  
    }  
 });
```

The alerts in the error function above give -
`xhr:<blank>

textstatus:parsererror

errorThrown: undefined`

Any pointers would be great !
Note : jquery : 1.3.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution I finally found!

IE is anal about UTF-8, not only that!
I was formulating my response as below:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                    content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Now FF & Chrome is good with this.
But for IE the utf8 should be like this:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                    content_type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

Note the caps UTF -->> **UTF-8**

To debug the issue, I threw my jquery and wrote a bare bones ajax function.

```
var xmlhttp = false;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari    
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xmlhttp.open("POST",urlToSend,false);    
    xmlhttp.send(af_pTempString);    
}    
else    
{// code for IE6, IE5    
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
    xmlhttp.open("POST",urlToSend,false);    
    // Do not send null for ActiveX    
    xmlhttp.send(af_pTempString);    
}    
//alert("xmlhttp.responseText : " + xmlhttp.responseText);    
document.getElementById('navHolder').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

If the encoding is incorrect, it'll give you this error in IE - **c00ce56e**

Comment: I got "af_pTempString is not defined" error when i copy pasted your code. What am i missing? What is "af_pTempString" actutally?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the Content-Type header is set to application/json.
2. Remove dataType: "json", and print the raw response you get in IE8. Maybe a different (not valid JSON) response is sent to IE(8) for some reason
3. Try with the latest version of jQuery, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Currently the content type is something like this --->> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> I inserted application/json in place of text/html and it gave the same error. After that I commented out 'dataType: "json"' but still same error. Trying jquery 1.4.2 now.

Comment: Its a django app. Hence the content-type is set as this - return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8').  Changed to 1.4.2 but didn't help.